# Extraer caracteres de un archivo de texto en Linux

Tags: linux, edittext, text

tengo una duda muy básica.  Tengo el siguiente archivo de texto (cdrag.txt) y quiero extraer solo el valor (número) que está justo después de `Cd       :`

```
forceCoeffs forceCoeffs execute:
  Coefficients
    Cm       : -3.99664 (pressure: -4.01246 viscous: 0.01582)
    Cd       : 2.13648  (pressure: 2.13673  viscous: -0.000249648)
    Cl       : 1.18858  (pressure: 1.18672  viscous: 0.00185425)
    Cl(f)    : -3.40235
    Cl(r)    : 4.59093
```

End

He probado con el comando:

```
cat cdrag | grep  "Cd       : " | cut -d':' -f2
```

Pero este comando me saca por pantalla "2.13648        (pressure", es decir, lo que hay entre los dos puntos, y no únicamente el valor 2.13648, que es mi objetivo.

Nota: este valor numérico no es siempre el mismo

¿Alguna idea de cómo podría hacerlo? Muchas gracias!

Answer (score 1):

Puedes hacerlo con una expresión regular de tipo Perl y con `grep`.

La expresión regular sería.

```
Cd\s+:\s*\K-?\d+(\.\d+)?
```

Que dice indica que encontrará:

- lo que tenga `Cd`
- seguido de uno o más espacios (`\s+`)
- luego dos puntos (`:`)
- luego seguido de un cero o más espacios (`\s*`)
- luego lo "olvidará" (con `\K`) para,
- ahora si, marcar una cadena que puede o no empezar con un menos (`-?` en el caso de los números negativos),
- luego con un número que tenga una o más ocurrencias (`\d+`)
- y luego seguido de la parte decimal (que puede o no tener) que sería una cadena que inicie con un punto, y que tenga más de un número después (`(\.\d+)?`).

Con el programa `grep` y los parámetros `-P` (para usar las expresiones regulares de tipo Perl) y `-o` (para mostrar únicamente lo encontrado y no toda la línea), quedaría algo así:

```
grep -Po 'Cd\s+:\s*\K-?\d+(\.\d+)?' cdrag.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Yo haría esto:

```
cat cdrag | grep "Cd       : " | cut -d':' -f2  | cut -d' ' -f2
```

Si el formato es estricto y los espacios no variarán en tu *input*.

Ahora bien, si necesitas algo un poquito más robusto en términos de variación de formato, considera usar un pequeño *script* en **awk**, o bien en **python**.

Answer (score 0):

Hay algo que no queda muy claro, entiendo que el fiechero es de varias líneas y que empiezan con el Cd, Cl, Cm, etc. Y que lo que pides es solo para este fichero en concreto, pues solo te falta una cosa mas, quitar lo que hay después del numero que buscas. A lo que ya tienes le añades el cortar por espacio

```
cat cdrag|grep "Cd : " | cut -d':' -f2 | cut -d' ' -f2
```

Al resultado, cortas separado por `' '` y te quedas con el segundo campo porque el primero es el espacio en blanco de delante del numero